# Plot charts dynamically for the range against same string values

Tags: vba, excel, charts

The sample data set is given at http://bit.ly/1L67ZFu
The charts I'm getting from these by the below code is given at http://bit.ly/1P73A2U

In the code below, the rows are fixed from 1 to 7. I am having dynamic number of depts and dynamic number od parameters say like I can have parameters till parameter 6 and each of parameters can occur for any number of times in column 1. How should I modify the code if I want to plot a chart all the parameters dynamically. I want the code to plot the chart for the rows against same parameter. Like I want in total 14 graphs if the number of paramerters are from parameter1 to parameter 7.Kindly suggest me modifications in code for this.

```
Sub PlotSeparateChartsByMergedFirstRow()
 Dim rUsed As Range, rMerged As Range, rChtData As Range
 Dim rChtDat1 As Range, rChtDat2 As Range
 Dim iColMerge As Long, iColData As Long
 Dim cht1 As Chart, cht2 As Chart
 Dim lastCol As Integer

 Const iChtHeight As Double = 175
 lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column     
 Set rUsed = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(7, lastCol))
 iColMerge = 1

 Do
    iColMerge = iColMerge + 1
    If iColMerge > rUsed.Columns.Count Then Exit Do

    If rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).mergecells Then
       Set rMerged = rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).MergeArea
       Set rChtData = rMerged.Resize(rUsed.Rows.Count)

       ' x values
       Set rChtDat1 = rUsed.Columns(1)
       Set rChtDat2 = rUsed.Columns(1)

       ' y values
       For iColData = 1 To rChtData.Columns.Count - 1 Step 2
          Set rChtDat1 = Union(rChtDat1, rChtData.Columns(iColData))
          Set rChtDat2 = Union(rChtDat2, rChtData.Columns(iColData + 1))
       Next

       ' charts
       ' 2007, 2010
       Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, rChtData.left,   rChtData.Height, rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart
       ' 2013
       'Set cht1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered, rChtData.Left, rChtData.Height, rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart
       With cht1
          .HasTitle = True
          .ChartTitle.Text = "=" & rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).Address(, , , True)

          .SetSourceData rChtDat1, xlColumns

       End With

       ' 2007, 2010
       Set cht2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart(xlColumnClustered, rChtData.left, rChtData.Height + iChtHeight, _
       rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart
       ' 2013
       'Set cht2 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered, rChtData.Left, rChtData.Height + iChtHeight, rChtData.Width, iChtHeight).Chart

        With cht2
          .HasTitle = True
          .ChartTitle.Text = "=" & rUsed.Cells(1, iColMerge).Address(, , , True)
          .SetSourceData rChtDat2, xlColumns
       End With

    End If
    iColMerge = iColMerge + rMerged.Columns.Count - 1
 Loop

 End Sub
```